# Parse yyyy-MM-DD String to Date yyyy-MM-DD in Android?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

```
String startDateStr = "2017-02-03"
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD",Locale.US);
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(startDateStr);
```

**2017-02-03** date is parsed to **Tue Jan 03 00:00:00 GMT+05:45 2017**

Did I
 miss something?

**Update**

I needed a string to be converted to a date object
while maintaining the same format.

The reason for this is I want to make use of `public boolean after(Date when)` method

Comment: I needed it to be parsed to yyyy-MM-DD

Comment: Did you find any solution? I don't understand why you have got negative points for this. Even I am looking for the same

Answer (score 5):

This will work ^_^

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
String startDateStr ="2017-02-03";
Date date = null;
try {
    date = inputFormat.parse(startDateStr);
    String startDateStrNewFormat = outputFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Little explanation of your output :

`D` is Day in year (1-365) 
`d` is day in month (1-31)

Check the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use SimpleDateFormat type for fomatter. You are creating DateFormat object but using SimpleDateFormat.

```
String startDateStr = "2017-02-03"
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(startDateStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you missed something. You used `DD` instead of `dd` in your yyyy-MM-**DD** format string. Here is how you do it:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
String formattedDate = sdf.format(new Date());
```